# What is the scientific name to humour that is based on surprise

Tags: names, science, humor

I remember browsing through Wikipedia one day, and coming across an article defining surprise-based humour. The article had a very specific scientific name, which doesn't have the actual word "surprise" in it.

To give an example of this kind humour, consider the following sentence:

"I have the body of a 20 years old model, it really takes a lot of space in my freezer."

I'd like to know the actual name of that kind of humour, and particular the link to the long gone Wikipedia article regarding it.

Thanks!

Comment: Pretty sure all humor is predicated on surprise, one way or another.

Comment: @DanBron Perhaps I mean in an exaggerated way then?

Comment: Old science, but science nonetheless: *black bile*?   The joke does seem a little splenetic.

Comment: Perhaps *paraprosdokian* or *garden-path sentence* then? Not sure those are specific to humor, though.

Comment: @DanBron Thanks dan, paraprosdokian is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: @user1337 That's first, and probably last, time I've ever heard that sentence in my life.

Comment: I'd call it a joke, and further, a *one-liner*

Comment: I'd have thought *all* types of humour/joke involve an element of "surprise". OP's example would normally be categorized as [wordplay](http://www.bizlike.co.uk/blog/inspiration/the-nine-classic-joke-forms-of-comedy-scriptwriting) (based on the "surprise" of realizing that the speaker isn't referring to her *own* body).

Comment: @Fumble: The OP's example sentence marks it as *paraprosdokian* which makes it a dupe.

Comment: @Robusto: True, but I don't think every paraprosdokian is necessarily "humorous", and obviously not every humorous utterance that includes an element of "surprise" involves paraprosdokians.

Comment: @Fumble: True, but that is the kind he's talking about, if we allow that he has expressed himself clearly.

Comment: Humor (other than the slap-stick variety and some types of crude "humor" that make you laugh out of uneasiness) is due to being surprised by the truth.